# CSS Merging (or) Minify is not working properly

Tags: performance, magento2.2.6, minified-js

We have installed some of the third party plugins on our Magento site. We have enabled minify CSS, JS for better performance.

But while looking source code, we have seen that the minification has not been applied for the third-party extensions.

Is this the case in Magento 2.2.6?

Comment: JS minification may not works for your 3rd party js files if those js coming from an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons behind the issue:

1. **The third party plugin that you are using is not compatible with
   Magento 2.2.6**: May be, the plugin is not updated to work with the
   specific version of the platform.
2. **JavaScript codes coming from an external resource**: The JavaScript
   files of the third party plugin might be associated with an external
   resource.